# Convert Oracle to Db2 query

Tags: oracle, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to convert below oracle query to Db2 . Below is the Oracle query

```
select stat.owner
                      ,stat.OBJECT_NAME
                      ,stat.STATISTIC_NAME
                      ,stat.VALUE AcsValue

                from v$segment_statistics stat
```

I want to Convert it to DB2 11 database supported query .This above  query is to find frequency of table usage .So Far I have tried to find the equivalent metadata tables . I am very new to DB2 . any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What platform of Db2 are you using?

Comment: It is installed in windows server

Comment: BTW consider improving the title of your question to explicitly mention the "table usage" requirement, or simply revise it to say something like "What is the equivalent of Oracle's v$segment_statistics system table in DB2?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `MON_GET_TABLE` table function https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053945.html

That will return things like logical reads by table. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0058774.html

Comment: Consider maybe installing Data Server Manager. That has a tree-map view that can show table activity by schema. Also try `dsmtop`.  I don't know Oracle, so can't really help without more details (ask another question). But generally just aggregate the info in the `MON` table functions.  (P.S. mark your question as answered/up vote any answers you find helpful)